# How to use python to draw a word with fixed width and fixed length?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

i want to use matplotlib to draw a word with fixed width and fixed length,but "pylab.mpl.font_manager.FontProperties" only can set size,how should i do?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share what you've tried already.

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed width and fixed length"?  Are you referring to pixels or points?  Are you wanting to automatically stretch text to fit a box?

Comment: yes,i want to stretch text to fit a box,how should i do ?